# mouse movement real time transmission from raspberry pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, mouse

i'm trying to send the coordinates of mouse connected to a raspberry pi to an ESP8266 in the same network.
I just wrote this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

device='/dev/input/event1'

mouseX="*(REL_X), value*"
mouseY="*(REL_Y), value*"


evtest "$device" | while read line; do
  case $line in
  ($mouseX) X=${line##*value } 
  curl 'http://192.168.0.4/ricevuto?X='"$X" &
  ;;
     
  ($mouseY) Y=${line##*value } 
   curl 'http://192.168.0.4/ricevuto?Y='"$Y" &
  ;;
  esac

done
```

the command "evtest" capture the mouse movements and the script extract the coordinates, curl send the data.

It works, but it's really SLOW! With the "&" at the end of the curls is faster but sometimes the coordinates are messed up...
Is there a way to establish a connection and just transmit data without make a request everytime?

Just to explain my final goal: i'm trying to use a mouse, connected to a raspberry pi, on multiple devices: in this case the receiver (esp8266) will be connected to a arduino leonardo that can recreate the mouse movement on an android TV.
Thanks for the help or any other simpler solution!

Comment: Of course there is _a way_, but you'd also have to adapt the receiving code, which you didn't show.

Comment: Sorry about that, of course I know that i have to adapt the receiver code, my question is more "general", asking the method, and not the code. After a day of test I reach almost good results with MQTT, but of course with the same "architecture"

Comment: It sounds like you're already working on a sophisticated solution - I'd have, for a start, just suggested a simple approach with piping through `sed` and `netcat`, but MQTT might be more promising. I don't know what you mean by _"architecture"_. Surely it's not optimal to have a shell loop which handles individual lines.

Comment: It means that the code is the same but with "mosquitto_pub" instead of curl. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check for these commands!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sketch of how the shell loop could be avoided:

```
evtest "$device" | sed -un 's/.*(REL_\([XY]\)), value /\1=/p' | …
```

The `…` can be a command like `netcat` or `mosquitto_pub -l`. The above will generate messages like `X=2` or `Y=1`, but the message format can be changed by using some other replacement than `\1=`.